# 20 volt drop in electric line

Tags: electrical, wiring, voltage

EDIT: Added photo and comment about other fixture.
[image: Photo shows red wire measuring 20v compared to the box and a mess of black and white wires]

I recently replaced an outdoor fixture because the old one wasn't working. The new one didn't work either, so I started sleuthing. It turns out there is a 100 volt difference between black and white, and a 20 volt difference between white and ground.

I went upline to the switch, and there is a random red wire that ends in the box, no wire nuts or anything. It's just trimmed off. That random wire has a 20 different volt difference from ground. Any ideas what is going on? We just bought this house a couple months ago and there is some... creative wiring.

Comment: How old is the house?  After mid 20s switches are suppose to have neutral at the box.  Having a red wire at the switch, seems like newer code, but wired wrong.

Comment: House is mid 60s, but this was clearly a later addition. The switch does have neutral and hot, as well as the red coming from somewhere and going to nowhere. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The switch(non smart) should not have neutral on it.  It might have a white wire being used as a hot on it(a switch loop).  Pictures of the wires at the switch and light will help.

Comment: Please [edit] to include a picture of the wiring in the switch box.

Comment: Also, I believe that a significant difference in voltage from hot-ground v neutral-ground can often be attributed to a lost neutral. However, wait for one of the electricians to pop by to confirm that. You could do a search here for "lost neutral".

Comment: You are being misled by "ghost voltage." Read this article, get yourself a dual impedance multimeter (any brand) and all will become clear: https://www.fluke.com/en-us/learn/blog/digital-multimeters/dual-impedance-digital-multimeters

Comment: Thanks all for the questions. To answer, roughly in order:
Switches don't have a neutral, but 5 meet up in the switch box. The light is just a black and white coming out of the wall, so no photo included. 
Lost neutral was helpful, thanks. 
I found another light here that had the ground wired in with the neutral. I'm guessing it was the same problem there, which the previous owners "solved" by linking the ground and neutral. That light is on a different circuit. Continuity testing showed a continuous neutral for the one wired to ground and discontinuous for the circuit w/ the 20v oddity.